# Viewport and render not looking as good as edit mode

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

newbie here

Everything is in the title, my view port and renders dont look as good as the edit mode. I tried raising the sampling but it doesnt seem to make things better. Here are some screenshots. I also attached the blend file. Do you have a solution ? Thank you

Blend file : https://we.tl/t-PRHdaLjWLp

Viewport : 
[image: Viewport]

Edit mode : 
[image: Edit mode]

Comment: Please tell and provide what is edit mode version and which is rendered version.

Comment: better post a simple blend with part that raise the issue, It can be something disabled from viewport, or different setup for render from viewport .... ? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Thanks I made the modifications to my post and attached the blend files. I hope the objects used are inclued, not sure how blender saves projects

Comment: To me there is not visible difference (your file downloaded), except for the ligthning which is different

Comment: Oh, that might be a hardware problem then ?

Comment: It looks like an aliasing problem but I'm not sure

Comment: Possibly. make sure your gpu driver is up to date and have a look at: https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: I tried opening it both in windows and macOS, same result (on the same hardware). I have a GTX970 so it is compatible

Comment: I would be weird that my gpu could display it fine in edit mode but not in viewport no ?

Comment: My bad: forget the bpu issue. I've it too effectively (did not undertood what you meant by "viewport" and "edit" modes... you wanted to say "rendered" I think)

Comment: It is due to the camera clipping/focal length. Set the "clip start" to something like 0.2.

Comment: Thank you so much ! That did it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lemon, I just needed to set the clip stat at 0,2